# UILabel can not be wrapped and aligned at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, text-alignment, word-wrap

I cannot wrap and align at the same time an `UILabel` displayed in a `UITableViewCell`.

I want some UILabels (displayed below with a white background) to be right aligned
and word wrapped if the text is too long. To clarify the sreenshots below:

- `UILabel` with a white background are the labels I am talking about
- I am using two different types of cell (respectively with blue and orange background)
- The `UITableView` has a something-like-pink background
- The `ViewController` in which the `UITableView` is displayed has a light gray background

Either is the alignment correct but the text is not wrapped (Actually the text "Long.. " is long, please see the second screenshot)

[image]

Or the text is correctly wrapped but it is not right aligned:

[image]

My code is based on this tutorial: [How to build a Table View with multiple cell types](https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-multiple-cell-types-2df91a206429)

Inside the code for the cell displayed with an orange background:

```
class AttributeCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel?
    let orange = UIColor(red: 1, green: 165/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    var item: AttributeLabelLabel?  {
        didSet {
            titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .white
            titleLabel?.setLabel(contentText: (item?.attributeNameFromLocalizable)!, alignmentText: .right)

            valueLabel?.backgroundColor = .green
            valueLabel?.setLabel(contentText: (item?.attributeValue)!, alignmentText: .left)

            self.backgroundColor = orange
        }
    }

    static var nib:UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    static var identifier: String {
        return String(describing: self)
    }  
}
```

I added an extension to `UILabel` to set the alignment and text of the two labels displayed on cell, the way how the text should be wrapped is the same for all labels.

With the extension below the label is aligned but not wrapped (see first screenshot above).

```
extension UILabel{
    func setLabel(contentText: String, alignmentText: NSTextAlignment){
        self.text = contentText
        self.textAlignment = alignmentText

        self.numberOfLines = 0
        self.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping     // inefficient alone
    }
}
```

If I want to have the text to be wrapped then I have to add a call to `sizeToFit()` but then short label (see label with the text "Short") is not right aligned (see second screenshot above).

```
extension UILabel{
    func setLabel(contentText: String, alignmentText: NSTextAlignment){
        self.text = contentText
        self.textAlignment = alignmentText

        self.numberOfLines = 0
        self.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        self.sizeToFit()            // allow text to be effectivly wrapped
    }
}
```

Why do I need to specify `self.sizeToFit()` on the documentation I have found only the use of `lineBreakMode` is mentionned to wrap a text ?

As I can not handle word wrapping and text alignement, I had the idea to compare the width of the UILabel with its text, and depending on the comparaison handling the alignment (for a text short enough) or the wrapping (if the text is too long). But I did not find how to get the UILabel´s width.

Another idea would be to create a custom UILabel and set all constraint, compression and resistance in code. For now there are no constraints:

[image]

[image]
Has someone already dealt with such problems?

Is it possible to handle text wrapping and text alignement at the same time ?

#### Note:

On the second screenshot the `UILabel` with a wrapped text overlapped the cell boundaries. It is not the first problem and I can live with that for now but if someone has an hint about that...
I actually use the following code to deal with cell with different heights:

```
cell?.estimatedRowHeight = 200
cell?.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Comment: For your second question, about the label bleeding outside of the bounds of your `UITableViewCell`, are you using Auto Layout? From your screenshots, you don't seem to have any constraints on that label. Make sure you have a constraint that ties the bottom of the `UILabel` to the bottom of its container view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few constraints.

To get a multiline label to wrap, it *must* have its width limited (how else would it know the text is too long?).

To get auto layout to adjust the cell's height, you need constraints on the content of the cell to "push down" the bottom of the cell.

So...

- Constrain your top-left label to `Leading: 0`, `Top: 0`, `Width: 77` (I'm using 77 as the width, based on your images).
- Constrain your top-right label to `Leading: 8` (to top-left label's trailing), `Top: 0`, `Trailing: 0`
- Constrain your bottom-left label to `Leading: 0`, `Top: 8` (to top-left label's bottom), `Width: 77` (or, width equal to top-left label)
- Constrain your bottom-right label to `Leading: 8` (to bottom-left label's trailing), `Top: 8` (to top-right label's bottom, or `Top: 0` to top of bottom-left label), `Trailing: 0`

then, add `Bottom` constraints of `>= 0` to each of the bottom labels.

I'm guessing either bottom label may wrap to multiple lines, so set each one to `Number of Lines: 0`

The layout:

[image]

the result:

[image]

Comment: It works!! it seems so simple when someone explains, thanks a lot @DonMag !!

Answer (score 0):

A `UILabel` can definitely be right-aligned and wrap on multiple lines. Here is an example:

[image]

Actually, the label content is misleading as it wraps on four lines! ;-)

This can be achieved through AutoLayout constraints and the right settings on the `UILabel`. This particular `UILabel` is constrained as follows:

- Vertically centred
- Leading edge to super view
- Width

Here are the constraints, as shown in Interface Builder:

[image]

Finally, to have a `UILabel` line-wrap to multiple lines, its `numberOfLines` property needs to be set to 0, either through Interface Builder or code.

You can also right-align the text using the `textAlignment` property, setting it to `.right`, again through Interface Builder or code.